# Javascsript generator confusing behavior

Tags: javascript, generator

I came across this article explaining generators https://modernweb.com/replacing-callbacks-with-es6-generators/

Which contains this example

```js
function* ticketGenerator() {
  for (var i = 0; true; i++) {
    var reset = yield i;
    if (reset) {
      i = -1;
    }
  }
}

var takeANumber = ticketGenerator();
console.log(takeANumber.next().value); //0
console.log(takeANumber.next().value); //1
console.log(takeANumber.next().value); //2
console.log(takeANumber.next(true).value); //0          <----- Why is this happening?
console.log(takeANumber.next().value); //1
```

What confuses me is the output of the `console.log(takeANumber.next(true).value);` line which is unintuitive.

Why wouldn't it print 0 1 2 3 0 instead of 0 1 2 0 1 ?

I tried running it in console to make sure there wasn't an error in the article but it worked as the article stated

Comment: Why would it yield `3` after executing `i = -1`?

Comment: I was under the impression that execution is paused immediately before yielding the next value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at it step by step using Python Visualizer (which can also visualize JavaScript). See [here](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=function*%20ticketGenerator%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20for%20%28var%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20true%3B%20i%2B%2B%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20var%20reset%20%3D%20yield%20i%3B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20%28reset%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20i%20%3D%20-1%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20takeANumber%20%3D%20ticketGenerator%28%29%3B%0Aconsole.log%28takeANumber.next%28%29.value%29%3B%20//0%0Aconsole.log%28takeANumber.next%28%29.value%29%3B%20//1%0Aconsole.log%28takeANumber.next%28%29.value%29%3B%20//2%0Aconsole.log%28takeANumber.next%28true%29.value%29%3B%20//0%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C-----%20Why%20is%20this%20happening%3F%0Aconsole.log%28takeANumber.next%28%29.value%29%3B%20//1&cumulative=false&curInstr=20&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=js&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false).

What happens is this:

- You call `next()` for the first time. The generator code runs from the beginning to the function until it reaches `yield 0`. The value `0` is returned and execution is paused.
- You call `next()` for the second time. The generator code receives `undefined` as return value from the previous `yield` and continues execution until it reaches `yield 1`. The value `1` is returned and execution is paused.
- You call `next()` for the third time. The generator code receives `undefined` as return value from the previous `yield` and continues execution until it reaches `yield 2`. The value `2` is returned and execution is paused.
- You call `next(true)`. **The generator code recevies `true` as return value from the previous `yield` and resets the counter to -1.** It then continues execution until it reaches `yield 0`. The value `0` is returned and execution is paused.
- You call `next()` for the last time. The generator code receives `undefined` as return value from the previous `yield` and continues execution until it reaches `yield 1`. The value `1` is returned and execution is paused.

Comment: Thanks, that clears it, my previous understanding was that execution is paused immediately before yielding